# How to customize the listview like youtube navigation drawer

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i would like to implement listview like below image. i know that i have to create custom adapter but i'm not getting the exact optimized way to implement the same.

[image]

Here the i will be getting information from database in cursor but i want to render them on listview something like below

```
Accounts
-------------------------
aaa@yahoo.com
bbb@gmail.com
ccc@yahoo.com

Countries
-------------------------
usa
uk
brazil
canada

food items
----------------------
Noodels
rice
chapati
```

I'm not getting how i need to add separator to make it look beautifully

Comment: then follow navigation drawer and do you have worked with that?you need to set separate layout for drawer window and have to click listeners to all..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sliding Menu`:
this is tutorial for it:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Or you can use this from github

https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/AndroidSideMenu

Comment: Hi, i m using https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu. this in my application, but i m not getting exact way to customize it

Comment: But I use it on my device and it works correctly try to use
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Hi, thats fine but i want to add separator to listview items like i showed in listview items. i'm getting data from adapter, but how to put separator at run time. i need that logic